# Using articles before the subject of a sentence?

Tags: nouns, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> "Smartphone is very useful"
>
> "Dog is loyal animal"

are these sentences incorrect? or do they require articles before the subjects? if yes, how to decide which article to use, definite or indefinite?

Comment: Nouns in English **always** require some sort of determiner. That may be the zero article (for example, in the case of plural nouns), but singular nouns always require something. Exceptions exist in, say, headline writing; both of your examples work there, but only there.

Comment: This question is more suited to the less-advanced site for English Learners, namely *English Language Learners*